# how to use google Geocoding in java?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding

I am developing a functionality for my project that when user enters 'Postal Code'  the co-ordinates(latitude, longitude) for the corresponding 'postal code' should display. the implementation platform is 'JAVA'.

I googled for the java api but i did not find any specific resource.

Any suggstions will be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite straight forward. E.g. have a look at the geocode method of [this class](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/ec08ce52854d7e4d568b3fc5c44f1310e82d3640/jdk-1.6-parent/gmap3-parent/gmap3/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/gmap/geocoder/Geocoder.java). Pass your postalcode (along with the country) to the method and you should be fine. (The GLatLng class can be found [here](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/ec08ce52854d7e4d568b3fc5c44f1310e82d3640/jdk-1.6-parent/gmap3-parent/gmap3/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/gmap/api/GLatLng.java) but should be replaced by you according to your needs.)

[edit]
I just saw that this example is still using [Google Maps v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/index), but it should be a breeze to convert it to [v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index).
In the linked documents you can also find the restrictions regarding the use of this service (paragraph "Usage Limits")

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, to test the result do i need to have any license form "Google" ?

Comment: gonna go out on a limb and say starting your answer with "its quite straight forward" is not the best approach

Answer (score 8):

You can (now) check out the open-source Java client library for Geocoding, Directions, DistanceMatrix, Elevation and TimeZone too: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

Answer (score 1):

You could try to write a REST client (using e.g. [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)) for [Google geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) RESTful web service.

Answer (score 1):

The docs on this are not new user friendly. For me the java docs worked best although theyre quite rigid: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.maps/google-maps-services/latest/com/google/maps/GeocodingApiRequest.html

Here is how to do so using the newest Google Geocoding API:

```
//use your google api key to create a GeoApiContext instance
GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey("xxxxxx").build();

//this will get geolocation details via zip 
GeocodingResult[]results = GeocodingApi.newRequest(context).components(ComponentFiler.postalCode("75002")).await(); 
System.out.println(results[0]);

//this will get geolocation details via address 
GeocodingResult[] results2 = GeocodingApi.geocode(context, "One Apple Park Way Cupertino, CA 95014").await();
System.out.println(results2[0]);

//another way to get geolocation details via address 
GeocodingResult[] results3 = GeocodingApi.newRequest(context).address("One Apple Park Way Cupertino, CA 95014").await();
System.out.println(results3[0]);

//geolocation details via lat lng 
GeocodingResult[] results4 = GeocodingApi.newRequest(context).latlng(latLng).await(); 
System.out.println(results4[0]);
```

from there you'll get a bunch of data on the returned location in the results array, you can parse it as you wish to extract your choice of data. heres an ex of what that data looks like....

```
[GeocodingResult placeId=ChIJyTSQVXm0j4ARmdUQoA1BpwQ [Geometry: 37.31317000,-122.07238160 (APPROXIMATE) bounds=[37.34159500,-121.99557710, 37.24799500,-122.14382300], viewport=[37.34159500,-121.99557710, 37.24799500,-122.14382300]], formattedAddress=MONTE VISTA, CA 95014, USA, types=[postal_code], addressComponents=[[AddressComponent: "95014" ("95014") (postal_code)], [AddressComponent: "MONTE VISTA" ("MONTE VISTA") (locality, political)], [AddressComponent: "Santa Clara County" ("Santa Clara County") (administrative_area_level_2, political)], [AddressComponent: "California" ("CA") (administrative_area_level_1, political)], [AddressComponent: "United States" ("US") (country, political)]], postcodeLocalities=[Cupertino, MONTE VISTA, Permanente]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way for doing it (include source):
http://halexv.blogspot.mx/2015/07/java-geocoding-using-google-maps-api.html

The blog explain how to do it without having and API_KEY and a way for filtering the locatiotions into the most probable one.

Give it a try.